# Creating a single page pdf file with array of images in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need create a single page pdf file with multiple images in iOS. i used this code:

```
- (void)createPDFWithImagesArray:(NSMutableArray *)array andFileName:(NSString *)fileName
{

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *PDFPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",fileName]];

 for (UIImage *image in array)
 {


    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    CGRect pagebounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

   CGRect imagebounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(PDFPath, pagebounds, nil);
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        [image drawInRect:imagebounds];



    }

  }

   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

but it is not generating pdf file and getting error can any body help me please...

Comment: [1094:190271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e84a70'

Comment: Are you sure that app is crashing in this method block ?

Comment: @ajayk Which line is the error on?

Comment: after getting this error i have allocated array=[[NSMutablearray alloc]init];  in side the for loop but it was generating empty pdf file..

Comment: Are you sure you are passing an array into the function?    If you pass an unintialized variable you are bound to get that error (Invalid Argunebt ..... and don't initialise the array within the function or  you will wipe out the images.

Comment: @paulo i am new to IOS can you please send some code..

Comment: Show me the code that you use to call the function and show the error log, you probably just need to validate the array --- if (array) {   createPDFWithImagesArray:array andFileName:fileName;}

Comment: above i mentioned the function which i used to call and these are the errors i am getting when i am trying generate pdf file" 2014-12-05 11:37:41.072 photopdf[1108:194697] -[__NSArrayM size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dd6070
2014-12-05 11:37:41.073 photopdf[1108:194697] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dd6070'"

Comment: -(void)imagePickerContoller:(SFMultiImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    
    [imagesselected addObject:info];
    
    
    NSLog(@" selcted images are %@",imagesselected);
    
    [self createPDFWithImagesArray:imagesselected andFileName:@"mypdf"];
    

}
by this function i called this method..

Comment: Let me check the codes I have for UIImagepicker. Its hard to read the code - you do understand that info will contain more than the images -  ......  please also check the address of images selected - the array you pass into the function if its nil or 000000   you need to initialise it.

Comment: where to initialize the array in the function...

Comment: In your case It needs to be a property , initialise it in -viewdidload  - info is a dictionary  the images are using the keys UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage ... and UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage  - I'm preparing some code for you but there are a few things that need to change

Comment: @paulo actually i am using the third party library for picking multiple images (SFMultiImagePickerController). i am not using UIImagePickerController for picking the images.after picking multiple images those are stored into NSMutableArray.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that .... scratch what I said  ...    Just initialise the array / property outside and try it - have not tried your third party picker.

Comment: @paulo i initialized the array outside it was generating empty pdf same as before..

Comment: You may need to read the documentation of your 3rd party picker, there is a lot of information in the media library it is not only the images I have a feeling that your code is not getting to the images.  If you are certain that you are following the instructions properly - just publish the new codes so people can see it - maybe reinitialisation at the wrong place.

Comment: i am sure that the picker is picking the images and passing them to above function but the problem is raising when i am trying to generate pdf file with those picked images.

Comment: In your For loop - put some NSLOG try to display the bounds (width and length of the image and see if there really are images in your array)  Lets try that first  there maybe other issues if the array has actual content.

Comment: Hi ajay, I'll save you some time -   info is an array of dictionaries - one of the way to get to the images is:     
        for (NSDictionary *imageInfo in info) {
            ALAsset *asset = [imageInfo objectForKey:SFImagePickerControllerAsset];
            
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset defaultRepresentation].fullScreenImage];
            [images addObject:image];
        }

Comment: Need to go now - I hope you fix it bye.

Comment: @paulo thanks for your help but the pdf is generating only with [index 0 object in the array].

Comment: Not sure what you mean but Index 0 means is the first item in the array - The code I inserted - if you are using it should be in a loop going through the items of info one at a time and saving the contained image into the array to be passed to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @kanan Vora i have solved my issue with this code

```
{

 CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(button.frame.size.width*5, button.frame.size.height*5+600);
    NSLog(@"page size %@",NSStringFromCGSize(pageSize));

    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectMake(0, 0, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height*3), nil);


    NSArray *arrImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", @"1.png",@"2.png", @"1.png", nil];
    float y = 220.0;

    for (int i=0; i<arrImages.count; i++) {


           UIImage * myPNG = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]];

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0.0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);






 [myPNG drawInRect:CGRectMake(120.0, y, myPNG.size.width, myPNG.size.height)];




//        y -= myPNG.size.height+1;
    }


    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```