# Combine multiple .pngs into one .pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, png

I'm trying to send a .pdf to my app, have it convent each page to a .png, edit photo, then convent them back into one .pdf. I can convert the .pdf to multiple .pngs but trying to convert them back into one .pdf is giving me problems it is exporting each page/image into its own pdf not one. This is just the quick and dirty code where i'm trying to send a .pdf, convert to .pngs, then back to a .pdf with out the editing of the .pngs right now. I've looked at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265 and [Creating a single page pdf file with array of images in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309194/creating-a-single-page-pdf-file-with-array-of-images-in-ios) but the images are not in an array... any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
      NSLog(@"Open URL:\t%@\n"
      "From source:\t%@\n"
      "With annotation:%@",
      url, sourceApplication, annotation);

CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);

size_t numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(SourcePDFDocument);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];

NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                               withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePathAndDirectory error:&error];

    NSLog(@"other error: %@", error);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
withIntermediateDirectories:NO
attributes:nil
error:&error];   
}

NSMutableData *pdfFile = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
CGDataConsumerRef pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)pdfFile);

for(int currentPage = 1; currentPage <= numberOfPages; currentPage ++ )
{
    CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, currentPage);
    // CoreGraphics: MUST retain the Page-Refernce manually

    CGPDFPageRetain(SourcePDFPage);

    NSString *relativeOutputFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d.png", @"temp", @"photo", currentPage];

    NSString *ImageFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:relativeOutputFilePath];

    CGRect sourceRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(ImageFileName, sourceRect, nil);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sourceRect.size, NO, 3);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0.0, sourceRect.size.height); 

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage (currentContext, SourcePDFPage); // draws the page in the graphics context

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeOutputFilePath];

    CGDataConsumerRef pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)pdfFile);
    // The page size matches the image, no white borders.

    CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceRect.size.width, sourceRect.size.height);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(pdfConsumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
    CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &mediaBox);

    CGContextDrawImage(pdfContext, mediaBox, [image CGImage]);

    CGContextEndPage(pdfContext);

    CGContextRelease(pdfContext);

    CGDataConsumerRelease(pdfConsumer);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *end = @".pdf";
    NSString *start = @"Documents/image";
    NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", start, timestamp, end]];

    [pdfFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", start, timestamp, end]);

}

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile and CGContextRelease(pdfContext) statements should be outside your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you've placed all images as a UIImageView on a UIScrollView):

```
  /* CREATE PDF */
  self.pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
  NSInteger pageHeight = 800;
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(self.pdfData, CGRectMake(0,0,768,pageHeight), nil);//768*792/612
  CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  for (int page=0; pageHeight *page < scrollView.frame.size.height; page++)
  {
      UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
      CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -pageHeight * page);
      [scrollView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
  }

  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

  /* EXPORT PDF */
  NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
  NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString* fileName = [self genRandStringLength:7];
  fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", fileName];
  NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

  // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
  [self.pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
```